# Why do these "while" and "when" parallel questions have definite answers (when both past or continuous is correct)?

Tags: tense, exam-questions, sequence-of-tenses

I am teaching a junior high school student at home in Japan and I just picked basketball worksheets to pique his interest but didn't look at them hard.

The answers are bolded in the questions below. Why are those answers chosen?

> When Carmelo Anthony **made** (shoot) a buzzer beater, the crowd **was cheering** (cheer) for hours!

> While LeBron James **was shooting** (shoot) a free throw, some of the fans from the other team **were booing** (boo). That **was** (be) very rude of them.

> 1. While Blake Griffin ___ toward the basket, his teammates ___ next to him.
>    **a. was dribbling/were running**
>    b. dribbled/ran
>    c. didn’t dribble/didn’t run

> 2. When Giannis Antentokoumpo ___ in the US, many fans ___ for him at the airport.
>    **a. arrived/were waiting**
>    b. was arriving/waited
>    c. arrived/waited

Comment: This looks like a stupid test. You could validly use a wide range of verb tenses, even including "Present as Future" + "True Future" *(When Carmelo Anthony **shoots** a buzzer beater, the crowd **will yell** loudly)*. There's no point in saying any particular combination is "correct" - the best we can do is say that *certain* combinations are inherently ***invalid***. For example, *When he **shot** a buzzer beater, they **will be yelling*** could never be valid.

Comment: CGEL, ACGEL, McCawley, Aarts ... all university texts. Decent intermediate texts are harder to recommend; possibly the Collins CoBuild grammars, and Practical English Usage by Swan wrote (and paraphrased) Edwin Ashworth in English Language Stackoverflow but I don't know any of them- perhaps you could quote one as source for a particular take on correct language which is fine for ESL.

Comment: A bane of many textbooks is that they teach tenses backwards - instead of using the tense to express what you mean and structuring the sentence around it, they teach the tense and make the student wedge it into rigid structures. I'm assuming today's lesson was about Progressive Past.

Comment: Not a lesson- a fun test.